# Prove AD+DA is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Suppose $A$ is a positive definite matrix such that $\lambda_{min}(A)\ge\frac12$ and $\lambda_{max}(A)\le 2$, and $D=A\circ I$ is the diagonal entries of $A$.

I want to prove that $AD+DA$ is positive definite.

One additional condition I am not sure if it helps: $A$ is a non-negative matrix in which all the elements are greater than or equal to $0$.

Comment: do you mean $AD + DA^T$ or $AD + DA$?  Why do you expect this to be true?

Comment: If $AD+DA$ is positive definite, it remains positive definite if we multiply $A$ and $D$ by the same positive factor. Thus the truthfulness of the statement that $AD+DA\succ0$ depends not on the conditions that $\lambda_\min(A)\ge\frac12$ and $\lambda_\max\le2$, but probably on the condition that $\kappa(A)=\frac{\lambda_\max(A)}{\lambda_\min(A)}\le4$. I have run a numerical experiment. Apparently, all $2\times2$ or $3\times3$ matrices $A$ such that $AD+DA$ are indefinite have $\kappa(A)>13$.

Comment: @user8675309 Here $A^T=A$ since A is a real symmetric matrix.

Comment: over reals, positive definiteness does not imply symmetry per se, so you should explicitly state this in the original post